# How to reload a node page after Comment submit

Tags: 7, ajax, comments

I'm using [AJAX Comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) to allow users to submit command using AJAX. I want to refresh the page after comment is submited.

Comment: Did you've "AJAX Comments Nodejs Integration" Sub-module enabled inside AJAX Comments module, seems like this refreshes the node on comment submit.

Comment: i enabled that module. but page not refreshing. any other module want to enable?

Comment: What's the point of using ajax comments for this scenario? might as well turn them off and the page will be refreshed when a new comment is added.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using below code:

```
 Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.ajaxCommentsAfter = function(ajax, response, status) {
 try {
     location.reload();
 } catch (e) {
     console.log('ajaxComments-After: ' + e.name)
 }
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Try [ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url === "ajax/use-proper-url" ) {
    location.reload();
  }
});
```